# encrypt the flv file

Tags: apache-flex, air, flv

I am now thinking of encrypting the flv file .
is there any way to do this by flex?
do you have some tutorial of example to do encrypt the flv file.

Answer (score 0):

Found this:
http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=745336

Comment: That links appears to obfuscate the location of the FLV file, not actually encrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to send FLV over the net via [SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssl), which is what I expect you want to do.  You'll need to

1. enable your webserver to use HTTPS (SSL)
2. change the `http://` to `https://`

Encrypting the FLV itself, on disk on the web server, means the browser that reads the files cannot read it--there is no point.

I suspect there is more to this question.  State why you want to encrypt the FLV and we can answer in more depth.